# Drag and Drop from chrome download bar and drop in a SWT Application

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to drag a a file from google chrome download bar and drop in a swt application, But I unable to drop that file.
I Wrote some code but it is not working in case of chrome, but it is working in case of mozila firefox.

```
int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY;
    Transfer[] types = new Transfer[] {FileTransfer.getInstance()};
    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(parent, operations);
    target.setTransfer(types);
    target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
      public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {

}});
```

Comment: At a guess it is not using `FileTransfer`. `URLTransfer` would be another possibility

Comment: URLTransfer is also not working.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in ByteArrayTransfer#isSupportedType and check what TransferData you are receiving. Maybe you can build your own Transfer type from that information.